# How do I use a GROUP BY, with a date range (i.e. a month) - MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, dateinterval

I am trying to create a query that displays the "total number of bagels sold" for a month and having the name of the bagel displayed next to it. I am also trying to include in the list the bagels that "weren't sold".

I have a table called **Order** I want to use the FOREIGN KEY I have in it called **O_BagelID** referenced from another table **Bagel** to count the number of times each item of Bagel appears in the **Order table**. By displaying the Bagel Name(Description), and counting the number of times a particular BagelID is presents.I also want to include the ones that do not appear at all.

So far I've tried doing something like this (which is clearly incorrect),

```
SELECT Bagel.Description,COUNT(`Order`.OrderID) AS 'Number Of Bagels Sold' FROM `Order`
LEFT JOIN Bagel
ON BagelID=Bagel.BagelID
GROUP BY Description WHERE Order_date BETWEEN '2016-2-1' AND '2016-2-29';
```

Comment: WHERE before GROUP BY

SELECT Bagel.Description,COUNT(`Order`.OrderID) AS 'Number Of Bagels Sold' FROM `Order`
LEFT JOIN Bagel
ON BagelID=Bagel.BagelID
 WHERE Order_date BETWEEN '2016-2-1' AND '2016-2-29' 
GROUP BY Description;

Comment: ^^ `WHERE` before `GROUP BY`, @BerndBuffen meant to say.

Comment: @  Michael Berkowski - UPS - sorry

Comment: on a side note you can just use `WHERE MONTH(Order_date) = 2`